# I am having problem using shortid in Javascript

Tags: javascript, module

I am having a project in which I require a npm module/script or anything you call i.e. **shortid**!

I downloaded it form npm by command `npm install shortid`
I have two files `index.html` and `index.js`

I want to use the **shortid** in my `index.js`
I used `const shortid = require('shortid');`
but it didn't worked as an error pops with `require is nit defined`

I tried `import shortid from 'shortid';` but it showed syntax error/can't use module outside ...

I am confuse how to do it!

can anybody plz help

Answer (score 0):

1. run `npm init`
2. run `npm i shortid`
3. create `index.js` and put this in it:

```
const shortid = require('shortid');

console.log(shortid.generate());
```

4. run `node index.js`

[console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quK6h.png)